Matplotlib - calling pyplot.show a second time removes all my previous formatting
I have a function in my code that grabs a CSV file (with pandas) and charts it using matplotlib.
Before the plt.show() line, I'm configuring how the chart looks (note that I have an INI file where I grab the numeric values from for some of these settings):
    plt.title(plotTitle,
              fontsize=chartTitleFontSize,
              pad=chartTitlePadding)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=chartTickLabelsFontSize)  
    plt.xticks(fontsize=chartTickLabelsFontSize)
    plt.text(0.01, 0.99,
             "Print Date: " + str(intDate.upper()),
             fontsize=12,
             horizontalalignment='left',
             verticalalignment='top',
             transform=plt.gca().transAxes,
             bbox=dict(facecolor='yellow',
                       alpha=0.5,)
             )
    plt.ylabel(yAxisLabel,
               fontsize=chartAxisLabelFontSize,
               labelpad=float(chartYaxisLabelPadding))
    print(tab1a + 'Generating the X-axis label...')
    plt.xlabel(frequencyFileHeader,
               fontsize=chartAxisLabelFontSize,
               labelpad=float(chartXaxisLabelPadding))
    plt.legend(loc='upper center',
               bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
               fancybox=True,
               shadow=True,
               ncol=10,
               prop={'size': chartLegendFontSize})
    plt.grid(which='major', axis='both', linestyle='-', linewidth=1.5)
    plt.minorticks_on() 
    plt.grid(which='minor', axis='both', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
    plt.xticks(ticks=[0.15, 1, 10, 80],
               labels=['0.15', '1', '10', '80'])
    plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = chartPlotDPI
    plt.rcParams["savefig.dpi"] = chartSaveDPI

    plt.show()
    

The function works great the first time:

However, when the function is called a second time, all my previous formatting disappears:

I have no idea if there's something I'm doing wrong or if it's a limitation of matplotlib.
I need to call the function a second time so that I can grab a different CSV file to chart, independent of the first one (or previous charts).

you might have better results if you use the matplotlib object oriented style (i.e. make a Figure and Axes (fig=plt.figure(), ax=fig.add_subplot()), then do all your formatting on the fig and ax instances (e.g. ax.set_xlabel() instead of plt.xlabel(), etc.). That makes sure that all your formatting will be applied to the figure and axes you expect them to

you might also get a better answer here if you can provide a [MCVE] which demonstrates the problem.

Got it. I can make a simple MRE but in the meantime, if I'm using subplots; does ax = individual (sub) plot settings and plt = global plot settings?

ax.some_method will operate on the Axes instance, ax. fig.some_method will operate on the Figure instance fig. plt.some_method will probably operate on the last active Axes or Figure instance. But it can sometimes be a little unclear exactly which the last active instance is, which is where I suspect your issues have come from

You were right! I had a line plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] that was messing up the 2nd iteration of plt.show. I deleted that for now and that seems to have fixed the issue for me.
